# Error Creating PDF in Reportviewer Azure

Tags: c#, pdf, azure, reportviewer

Im trying to export to PDF in Windows Azure, everything works Ok in my local enviroment, but when i test in my azure website it shows "Parameter Is Not Valid".

Any Help?

Comment: Could you show the code that you use to export the PDF file ? Also, is it stored in local storage or Azure Account storage (blobs) ? Then, give some more information what you have tried, the environment you are using (cloud service, azure website, etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same issue. Try switching the `App service plan pricing tier` from `Basic` from `Shared`. You can do this in the Scale tab.

Comment: You should change the plan to not from Basic of course. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do PDF generation server-side with WAWS because we don't allow the necessary APIs. Your options are to use a Web Role or to use an Azure VM.

As of right now, this is by-design. Some APIs are not allowed in WAWS for security and performance reasons. The GDI APIs that are necessary for generating PDF files are among those that are blocked.

Answered by Jim Cheshire | Microsoft, Monday, November 04, 2013 5:31 PM

This is a known issue and is related to GDI see this [Windows Azure forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/b4a6eb43-0013-435f-9d11-00ee26a8d017/report-viewer-error-on-export-pdf-or-excel-from-azure-web-sites?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)